# appsody build + dockerFile getting failed

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile

when I run the below command it's throws error:

```
  appsody build -f Dockerfile
```

Found existing deployment manifest D:\Work\loyalty-and-rewards-management-microservice\Dockerfile
[Error] D:\Work\loyalty-and-rewards-management-microservice\Dockerfile formatting error: error unmarshaling JSON: while decoding JSON: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type cmd.DeploymentManifest

Content of Dockerfile is below

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/nodejs-12:1-59

USER root

# Install OS updates
RUN yum install --disableplugin=subscription-manager python2 -y \
    && yum clean --disableplugin=subscription-manager packages \
    && ln -s /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/python \
    && useradd --uid 1000 --gid 0 --shell /bin/bash --create-home node

RUN npm -v

RUN rm -rf /project/user-app/node_modules && mkdir -p /project/user-app/node_modules

RUN chown -hR root:0 /project

# Install stack dependencies
WORKDIR /project

RUN npm install --unsafe-perm --production

# Install user-app dependencies
WORKDIR /project/user-app
RUN npm install --unsafe-perm --production
RUN echo 'Installing libaio package'
RUN yum install libaio libnsl -y
RUN echo 'Installing the oracle rpm'
RUN rpm -i oracle-instantclient19.9-basiclite-19.9.0.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm
RUN npm run build
RUN cp dist/app.js ../../
RUN chown -hR node:0 /project \
    && chmod -R g=u /project

WORKDIR /project

ENV NODE_PATH=/project/user-app/node_modules

ENV NODE_ENV development
ENV PORT 3000

USER node

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: Please post relevant configuration and deployment files, such as your full Dockerfile

Comment: added the Dockerfile detail

Comment: From [the docs](https://appsody.dev/docs/cli-commands/#appsody-build) it seems that the `-f` flag is for a specific deployment yaml file, not a Dockerfile. What happens when you just run `appsody build`?

Comment: failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to build LLB: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c npm install --unsafe-perm --production]: runc did not terminate sucessfully
[Error] exit status 1